# Unable to execute Maven .jar

Tags: java, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

As a preface (you can skip this), I am a relatively inexperienced programmer (as compared to an industry professional), and wanted to try my hand at using Maven as a dependency manager and as a maybe better way of generating self contained .jar files, for my senior science fair project.

(Start reading here if you skipped previous paragraph)
I am able to clean, validate, compile and package my Maven project. The .jar file is generated, in my file explorer it is recognized as an executable .jar file. I am using JDK 11.0.2. When I double click on the .jar file in my file explorer my cursor doe the little "im doing something" spinning blue circle for a split second before nothing happens. When I attempt to run the file using

```
java -jar Project-Name-alpha.jar
```

I am given the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/CompanyName/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

The relevant section in my pom.xml file are:

```
  <groupId>com.CompanyName</groupId>
  <artifactId>ProjectName</artifactId>
  <version>alpha</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
          <classpathPrefix>dependency-jars/</classpathPrefix>
          <mainClass>com.FoxInnovations.Main</mainClass>
        </manifest>
       </archive>
     </configuration>
  </plugin>



   <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id> 
            <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
      <id>copy-dependencies</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
          <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
      </plugin>        <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id> 
            <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
      <id>copy-dependencies</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
          <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
      </plugin>
```

I thought that the issue might be that I don't have the correct java JRE but was unable to find a JRE 11 and I thought that JDKs in general included the corresponding JRE.

I would bet that I am probably making some noob mistake I have overlooked.

If I mistakenly didn't include something that is important to solving this problem please let me know and I will add it as soon as I can.

Comment: It seems you have java 8 in your path. Execute java --version to see if it points to java 8 and correct it in your JDK_HOME and PATH to point to Java 11.

Answer (score 0):

You're executing the jar with a version of java that is less than the version used to compile. It is likely that you need to set the java target and source for the maven compiler plugin.

```xml
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.11</maven.compiler>target>
</properties>
```

Comment: close tag not added properly for </maven.compiler.target>